# changing opacity on hover with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Here's a jsfiddle of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/bkWaw/

I'm trying to get the text to display when the item-overlay is hovered, but for some reason the opacity isn't changing. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code

HTML:

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="item-overlay">
        <div class="item-hover">text</div>
    </div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x300" />
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.item a { display: block; color: #666;  font-style: italic; font-weight: bold;}
.item a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
.item-overlay { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: transparent;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.item-overlay:hover { background-color: rgba(233, 115, 149,0.8);}
.item-hover { color: white; z-index: 999; position: absolute; opacity: 0; width: 100px; height: 100px;}
```

JS:

```
$('.item-overlay').hover(
function () {
    $(this).find('item-hover').css("opacity","1");
},
function () {
    $(this).find('item-hover').css("opacity","0");
}
);
```

Comment: find('.item-hover') you are missing the dot for class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bkWaw/3/)

Use `.` for a CLASS

```
$(this).find('.item-hover').css("opacity","1");
```

P.S. in jsFiddle you did not set the jQuery library, and what you want is doable in pure CSS but I think you know that as soon you use transitions...